# Word 2016 - How to have linked text in footers to update quickly but also have different page numbers in the footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Edited question after resolution:  I want different page numbers in each footer but I also want other additional text in the footer that must be the same on every page. How is that done?

Here is a good one for WORD 2016 power users. 6 pages in a document. Footers are all unlinked to accommodate different pages numbers on each page in the footer. For example, Page x of 6. However, there is other text in the footers that you want to be the same on every page and don't want to have to update every pages footer. Answer: Use the page X of Y feature for the page numbering and leave the footers linked. Hope this satisfies the moderator/sysadmins.

Tried using quick parts fields and that works great for text in the body of a word document. You can just highlight the whole body of every page in the document and update but for footers you cannot highlight all the text in every footer at the same time.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't just use the quick parts fields for Page and NumPages in the normal way.

Comment: I could use those for page numbers but I don't think that would solve my problem regarding the text. I have text in the footer that I want connecting to one instance of the same text in the body and beginning of my document. I want to be able to change the text in the body of the document and have the ability to quickly have all the text in all the footers change to the same as in the body.

Comment: What problem with the text? You say the other text in the footer should be the same on every page. If you put text (other than quick parts fields) in the footer, it will appear unchanged on each page..

Comment: Not if the footers are all un-linked. If linked yes they will all change by changed the text in one of them.

Comment: Appreciate you guys reading and responding to this. Wish i could share the doc with someone to show me how I might fix it to work the way I want.

Comment: So your actual question is how to link the text in unlinked footers? If so, you might want to edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: JOB TITLE: IT Specialist (CUSTOMER SUPPORT), GS-2210-9
ANNOUNCEMENT: NCBF173351706069                            Page 1 of 6

Comment: That is an example of what I'm trying to do. I want the page numbers to change on each page of course but I want the text to look the same on every page when I edit it. Applying for jobs. Massive numbers of edited resumes. LOL.

Comment: Your right. I did ask that in the question, just not in a straight forward way. My apologizes.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by linked/unlinked, and why do you think it's necessary to unlink them?  Page X of Y doesn't require anything unusual.  Page numbering is an automated feature.  Standard text can be incorporated into the footer or you can use a field.

Comment: Ok, I've got it fixed. I went back and re-linked the footers and got the Page X of Y feature to work correctly for me now. With the footers linked I only have to change the text in the first footer and the rest follow. Not bad. Sorry, for taking up anyone's time and thank you to you guys who responded. I think I was just really tired and was unable to think clearly, focus and solve the problem on my own last night. I live on my PC and usually figure these simple things out on my own when others who are not good with computers come to me for help.

Comment: Great that you got it fixed.  Consider posting an answer explaining how you did it.  That will help others with a similar problem.  You can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark that will be next to it.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved and that there is a proven solution here.

Comment: Re-linked the footers, used the Page X of Y feature. This allowed me to have different page numbers in the footer but the same text in each. I have no checkmark to indicate this is the answer.

Comment: "I have no checkmark to indicate this is the answer" – because the above are all comments, some of them abuse the purpose of commenting. E.g. relevant information should be in the question body, you can [edit] the question to place them there. At this moment the question is unclear and one has to read the comments to fully understand you; not the best layout. Your last comment looks like a short answer but it should go into the answer field below. Then there would be a checkmark for you to click. Consider taking our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Re-linked the footers, used the Page X of Y feature. This allowed me to have different page numbers in the footer but the same text in each. Not sure why this needs more explanation unless you are even less knowledgeable than I. It seems straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to footer section in the tab(ribbon)
2) Select the template depending on your requirement
3) Fill the fields that you want to remain on all pages
4) Wherever you want to insert page number, you select page number from the above ribbon

I have tried this and it works.